# Finding max of a memory array in assembly

Tags: solidity, assembly, bit-manipulation

Practicing my solidity assembly skills and I'm using foundry to test this function. For most inputs it works, but fails when

1. There is a 0 present in the array
2. Possibly duplicate values present in the array (?)

I've included failing tests below.

```
 function maxOf(uint256[] memory a) public pure returns (uint256 max) {
        assembly {
            // grab the length of the array
            // first 32 bytes of the array is its length
            let len := mload(a)

            // first element is actually 32 bytes bytes after, so grab it
            let element := add(a, 0x20)

            // grab the current max
            max := mload(element)
            for { let end := add(element, mul(len, 0x20)) } // end = pointer to first element location + length*32 bytes per word
            lt(element, end) { element := add(element, 0x20) } {
                // move onto the next word in the array
                // x ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y));
                let ele := mload(element)
                max := xor(max, and(xor(max, ele), mul(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, lt(max, ele))))
            }
        }
    }
```

```
[FAIL. Reason: Assertion failed. 
Counterexample: calldata= // omitted for cleanness 
args=[[0, 0, 75557863725914323419136]]] 
testMax(uint256[]) (runs: 2, μ: 62897, ~: 62897)
```

and

```
[FAIL. Reason: Assertion failed. 
Counterexample: calldata= // omitted for cleanness
args=[[1, 1, 75557863725914323419136]]]
testMax(uint256[]) (runs: 41, μ: 9460, ~: 9433)
```

The whole shtick is that I use some [bithack](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compute-the-minimum-or-maximum-max-of-two-integers-without-branching/) `x ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y))` in order to find the max of two numbers without branching.

I `mul(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)` as to obtain the two's complement of `(x < y)`, so we can get `-(x < y)`. I think that this is the problem but I'm not sure.

Comment: Shouldn't the value `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` be much bigger?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to calculate the maximum between two numbers

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: ISC
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract X {
    function maxOf(uint256 x, uint256 y) public pure returns (uint256 max) {
        assembly {
            max := xor(x, and(xor(y, x), sub(gt(x, y), 1)))
        }
    }    
}
```